# string behaviour in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am reading a C course (it is dutch so probably you won't know) and there is a small exercise to understand string behaviour. Therefor i created a small C program to start the exercise but already the first output of my program is (for me) astonishing.

Source of my C program :

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void printString(char *string)
{
    printf("0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19\n");
    printf("%c ",string[0]);
    printf("%c ",string[1]);
    printf("%c ",string[2]);
    printf("%c ",string[3]);
    printf("%c ",string[4]);
    printf("%c ",string[5]);
    printf("%c ",string[6]);
    printf("%c ",string[7]);
    printf("%c ",string[8]);
    printf("%c ",string[9]);
    printf("%c  ",string[10]);
    printf("%c  ",string[11]);
    printf("%c  ",string[12]);
    printf("%c  ",string[13]);
    printf("%c  ",string[14]);
    printf("%c  ",string[15]);
    printf("%c  ",string[16]);
    printf("%d  ",string[17]);
    printf("%d  ",string[18]);
    printf("%d\n",string[19]);
}

void main(){

    char str[20];

    strcpy(str,"Dag grootmoeder!");
    printString(str);
}
```

I compiled with gcc (no special switches) and ran the program several times :
(For the English speaking people `Dag grootmoeder! == Hi grandma!`)

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19

D a g   g r o o t m o  e  d  e  r  !    94  -90  111

$./oefString 

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19

D a g   g r o o t m o  e  d  e  r  !    51  -12  96

$./oefString 

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19

D a g   g r o o t m o  e  d  e  r  !    -17  -117  28

$./oefString 

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19

D a g   g r o o t m o  e  d  e  r  !    96  15  -28

$./oefString 

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19

D a g   g r o o t m o  e  d  e  r  !    -20  -46  -18

$./oefString 

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19

D a g   g r o o t m o  e  d  e  r  !    68  -75  58
```

Here is the question :

1) Why do I get rubbish values for the last 3 indexes of str ? At first I was also `printf()`'ing them with `%c` and noticed the chars changed, that is why I used `%d` thereafter to display the integer values.

2) Why do these values change? I do nothing more then copying the same string using `strcpy()` into str.

Thx for taking time to read and even more thanx for those who respond !

Jorn

Answer (score 8):

You're simply acessing the memory **past the end of the string**. You didn't fill it so you can find anything there - so that's why on each run you find something else.

In C "strings" are actually `0`-terminated arrays (or pointers to memory). So if you print the characters using `"%d"` you will notice the very last element, right after `!`, is `0`.

If you want it to be predictable, you can initialize your string before using it:

```
memset(str, 0, sizeof(str));
```

or

```
char str[20] = {0,};
```

As a side note, it's `int main`, not `void main`.

Comment: * I figured i was seeing indeed memory but i am reserving 20bytes with the initialisation of char str[20]; (or so i assume).
Is it then some memory optimisation to fill unused memory of my reserved 20bytes ?

Comment: thx, i noticed when disabling stack randomisation these values stay the same.echo "0" > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space

Comment: @JornDePril If you don't initialize your array it can contain anything.

Comment: about your side note. Isn't it 'int main' when having exit codes and 'void main' when not returning anything ?

Comment: @JornDePril Read about it [here](http://c-faq.com/ansi/voidmain.html). Also [this](http://c-faq.com/ansi/voidmainbooks.html) is funny enough :-)

Comment: ok, i apparently reading a course where the author is among target audience. He always uses void main ... I'll start using int for main function now

Answer (score 0):

```
char str[20];
...
strcpy(str,"Dag grootmoeder!");
```

str starts with random values (whatever was there last time that RAM was used)
Now you copy a 16 byte string into it, leaving the last 3 chars on there initial (random) values, so these are printed out

Answer (score 0):

Objects defined at block scope without any storage-class specifier (e.g., your `str` array object) have automatic storage duration.

Automatic objects that are not explicitly initialized have indeterminate value. So after your  `str` object declaration, all array elements have an indeterminate value. By copying the string `"Dag grootmoeder!"` in the array you make the first 17 (the length of the string + the trailing null character) elements have a specified value. This leaves the last 3 elements of your array with an indeterminate value.

C says that an indeterminate value is either unspecified or a trap representation. C also says that reading a indeterminate value is an undefined behavior, so as usual with undefined behavior, anything can happen when you do this, such as printing garbage.